# Why does my nested loop not check the second element of vector (empty string)?

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

I'm a bit stuck on this one.. my code should stop capitalising the characters when it hits the first empty string ( text[1] ).. but when I put a breakpoint in and step forward; the third string is considered straight after the first. The second element is ignored. The exercise is to print all strings but only capitalise the first one.

```
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> text = { "One, two, three-four-five. Once I caught a fish alive.", "", "Six, seven, eight-nine-ten. Then I let it go again.", "", "Why did I let it go? Because he bit my finger so.", "", "Which finger did he bite? This little finger on my right!"};

    for (auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); ++it) {
        for (auto it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end() && !it->empty(); ++it2) { //empty string in text[2] never satisfies second condition
            *it2 = toupper(*it2);
        }
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
   };
}
```

Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: Focus on where you put your condition `&& !it->empty()`... (Spoiler: Did you really intend to stop the inner loop if `it->empty()` is `true`?)

Comment: If you want to capitalize the string items until you encounter an empty string, the test should be somewhere in the first loop, the one regarding the vector items

Comment: _Why does my nested loop not check the second element of vector_ If the `string` is empty then `it2 != it->end()` is false from the beginning. The other part of the condition will be either not tested or else return `true` (always).

Comment: Ah, of course. I think I've been staring at this one too long. Thanks for your help people. :)

Comment: Not that code staring is bad in any case. Sometimes it really helps (me) but you have to do it long enough... :-) (I must admit that sometimes it's even more efficient to sleep over an annoying bug. Big trouble in the evening, fixed in a moment next morning.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to stop capitalizing after the first empty string, and not after the first empty character, something like:

> ONE, TWO, THREE-FOUR-FIVE. ONCE I CAUGHT A FISH ALIVE.
>
> Six, seven, eight-nine-ten. Then I let it go again.
>
> Why did I let it go? Because he bit my finger so.
>
> Which finger did he bite? This little finger on my right!

That could be done with only one loop and transforming the whole string:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> text { "One, two, three-four-five. Once I caught a fish alive.", "", "Six, seven, eight-nine-ten. Then I let it go again.", "", "Why did I let it go? Because he bit my finger so.", "", "Which finger did he bite? This little finger on my right!"};

   for (auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end() && !it->empty(); ++it) {
       std::transform(it->begin(), it->end(),it->begin(), ::toupper);
   };
   
   for (auto const& str : text) {
       std::cout << str << std::endl;
   }
}
```

NOTE: As @user4581301 has pointed out, bear in mind that negative values (like extended ASCII) yield UB and you should decide what to do (i.e., casting via `[](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); }` as suggested in the comments).

Comment: Almost right. `for (auto const& str : text)` will repeat the first string.

Comment: @user4581301 Not sure what you mean, the second loop is just to print out the whole vector: https://godbolt.org/z/o3dnjq7j8

Comment: Ach! I missed the other change. Standing down.

Comment: That leaves only one minor niggle: `::toupper` flips out of given a `signed char` that has a negative value. [See here for details and a fix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper#Notes)